# Bootstrap accordion with anchor tag inside it

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to develop a web based application using Angularjs. I used anchor tag  inside bootstrap's uib-accordion-group and it works like expected but shows error in console.

### This is the error on console:

```
angular.min.js:108 Error: [$compile:ctreq]       
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/$compile/ctreq?
p0=uibAccordion&p1=uibAccordionGroupat Error (native)
at http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:6:423
at u (http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:59:464)
at M (http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:62:331)
at http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:70:96
at h (http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:54:463)
at http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:54:17
at http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:58:416
at http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:55:453
at r (http://localhost:63342/ROUTING/lib/angular.min.js:60:435)
```

When i try to visit Bootstrap's documentation it suggested **to override the accordion-group template to use div elements instead of anchor elements** but i don't understand how to implement it.  Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you get the error when you click on the accordion to show it?

Comment: @Tjaart van der Walt, I get error when i click the anchored element. not by clicking the accordion heading.

Comment: this jsfiddle I made uses the `data-target` attributes instead of `href`: https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/urw7bca8/ the test2 link is the working example

Comment: @Tjaart van der Walt, Thank you for ur immediate answer but, i used the anchor tag inside uib-accordion-group.